# remove padding to the right of input fields

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I'm having this flexbox with multiple input fields. However, I cannot get it to look like I want to. Here's the code:

```css
.inputSettings {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 750px;
}

.inputSettings > form {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  flex: 1;
}

.inputSettings > form > input {
  width: 165px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputSettings">
  <form>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  </form>
  <form>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  </form>
  <form>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  </form>
  <form>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  </form>
  <form>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  </form>
  <form>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  </form>
</div>
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rz94hwbv/2/

What I want is to evenly space the input fields inside of that flexbox in a way that the leftmost input field's border touches the left border of the box, while the rightmost inputfield's border touches the rightmost border. As you can see, there's always some padding to the right of each input field. I tried everything I can think of but I can't come up with a decent solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean like this - https://jsfiddle.net/rz94hwbv/7/ ?

Comment: The problem is the `flex:1` on the form and the restructed width on the input....With `flex:1` the form is always going to be as wide as it can.

Comment: Something like this one ?? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0ZvB.jpg

Comment: Or this - https://jsfiddle.net/rz94hwbv/13/

Comment: Thanks all, flex-direction: column did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see is with the `flex:1;` in contrast to the limited width of the `.inputSettings > form > input`. If you want the fields to touch the sides then the inputs need to have flexible growth.

```css
.inputSettings {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 850px;
  border-right: 12px solid purple;
}

.inputSettings > form {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.inputSettings > form > input {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputSettings">
<form>
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</form>

<form>
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</form>
  
  <form>
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</form>
  
  <form>
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</form>
  
  <form>
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</form>
  
  <form>
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</form>
  
  <form>
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</form>
</div>
```